# web2py - translate login page

Tags: web2py

How can translate login page of my system

by using this url: http://ip:8000/init/default/user/login

display by default two text boxes username and password how can i translate these labels.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you looking for a website translation service?

Comment: no, in the web2py technology the url: http://ip:8000/init/default/user/login draw by default two text boxes "username,password" and button Submit and i want to make my system support many languages so i wanna to translate the words "username,password" so how to use T to translate them.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model db, at the bottom, you can do:

```
db.auth_user.username.label=T("username")
db.auth_user.password.label=T("password")
```

and then via the administrative interface create click on [design][languages] create a language file like "fr-fr.py" and i will present you an interface to translate "username" and "password".

When a visitor has a browser set to "fr-fr", the visitor will see the translated labels.

Comment: It works fine by using the following lines:
`auth.settings.table_user.username.label=T("Username:")
auth.settings.table_user.password.label=T("password")
`
Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there any reason web2py does not use translatable labels in this case out of the box?